# UICollectionView cell dequeue issue with custom selection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a very frustrating problem with UICollectionView and its dequeuing mechanism.

In a nutshell, I have a custom UIView with a label inside. I set this up as the selection background view in my custom cell as follows:

```
//My Custom Cell Class    
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
        self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

        if(self){
            _selectionView = (MyCustomView *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyNibName" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
            self.selectedBackgroundView = _selectionView;
            [self bringSubviewToFront:_selectionView];
        }
        return self;
    }
```

Note that all the layout work, etc for both the cell and `selectedBackgroundView` is done in the nibs.

Whenever the cell is selected, I'd like to set custom text in the label for `selectionView` so in my custom cell I also have the following method:

```
//In my Custom cell class
- (void) setSelectedViewLabelText:(NSString *)paramText{

    if(!self.isSelected){
        return;
    }
    self.selectionView.label.text = paramText;   
}
```

To set the text I have in my UICollectionViewController:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    MyCellClass *selectedCell = (MyCellClass *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [selectedCell setSelectedViewLabelText:someString];  
}
```

The problem is that whenever the UICollectionView recycles the cell, it inits them again and obviously the setSelectedViewLabelText method isn't called.

I have an annoying feeling that I may have to track the selected indexPaths and enumerate through them to see if a cell is selected and call the method, but I have potentially large data sets and can foresee how this will become a performance problem.... any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of your selected cell, like:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    MyCellClass *selectedCell = (MyCellClass *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [selectedCell setSelectedViewLabelText:someString];
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

In `cellForItemAtIndexPath` check indexPath:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //.......

    if([selectedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]){
        [cell setSelectedViewLabelText:someString];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, I probably should have mentioned that I allow multiple selection in the collection view, so my concern is that doing enumerateObjectsUsingBlock for the array of selected index paths is going to hit performance...